# Get new post meta data when (custom) post is saved

Tags: posts, customization

When I save my post (custom post type: project) I want to get the meta data for a specific key that I just inserted. Based on the value of that key I insert a product in WooCommerce.

What happens is that I get the **past** value for the meta key, instead of the **current/new** one. Here's the code I use:

```
function shortened($post_id){

   $key_verkoop_ja_nee = "kaart_verkoop";
   //$value_verkoop_ja_nee = get_post_meta($post_id, $key_verkoop_ja_nee, TRUE);
   //$value_verkoop_ja_nee = $GLOBALS["wp_object_cache"]->cache["post_meta"][$post_id][$key_verkoop_ja_nee][0];
   //$value_verkoop_ja_nee = $_REQUEST[$key_verkoop_ja_nee];
   $value_verkoop_ja_nee = $_POST[$key_verkoop_ja_nee];

   if($value_verkoop_ja_nee == "Yes"){
       //Do a lot of stuf
   }
}

add_action( 'save_post_project', 'shortened', 999 );
```

$_POST and $_REQUEST don't return any value at all, get_post_meta and the $GLOBALS return the past value. I tried edit_post instead of save_post, in/decreased the importance (999) and used global $post in the function. Nothing works.

Any idea how the get the new inserted meta value?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Use `add_action( 'save_post', 'shortend', 999);`

and put this in your function as first.

```
if ( 'project' != $_POST['post_type'] )
    return $post_id;
```

If this doesn't work then you should `echo $_POST;` and see if kaart_verkoop is part of the array.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Augus. I already tried this and unfortunately didn't work. However, good idea to check all $_POSTs (should have figured that out myself...). I used Advanced Custom Fields to create meta boxes and instead of pushing the meta data into meta data, ACF uses an array of "fields". There I could find the keys and the values. So thanks!